# ClassNotFoundException Thrown using MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, classnotfoundexception

I am struggling with finding the reason why this code locks up. As far as I know, I am declaring the correct permissions in my manifest file as shown below. I have tried running it on an actual device(Droid x w./ 2.3.3) and an AVD to no avail. I've attached the logcat as well which brought me to the classnotfound exception. I have cleaned the project, and verified that the maps.jar is included in the googleapi's package, which I've also used as the target for the application. (Google API's 2.3.3).  Not sure where to go from here.

```
Activity Code:

'package com.SmartPark;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
//import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;



public class SmartParkActivity extends MapActivity {
 //** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout linearlayout;
    MapView mapView;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    Drawable drawable;
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(42392400,-83134700);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    public double[] gps=new double[2];
    public boolean setgps;
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    //TextView tvl; //latitude display
   // TextView tvlong;//longitude display
    int lat2;
    int longitude2;
    public float z;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greendot1);
        itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
       mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
       // tvl =  (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.gpslview);
      // tvlong =  (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.gpslongview);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

            return false;
    }

     @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();


        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0,
                locationListener);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 500);



    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

       lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

       lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        }






    //}
 // helper method to schedule the postdelayed mhandler at specified interval
    private boolean foo() { 
        setgps=false;


        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 500);

        return true;
    };


    //Method to acquire set gps variable and display it. update overlay if     possible
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {  

               mapOverlays.clear();
               GeoPoint point = setgeopoint(gps[0],gps[1]);
               OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
               mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
               itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

              // tvl.setText("Latitude:"+gps[0]);
               //  tvlong.setText("Longitude"+gps[1]);
                 // z=(float)android.location.Location.getSpeed();
                 setgps=foo(); //reschedules the task

    }; 
    };

    //math functions

   //convert gps double to an int and set to GeoPoint
    public GeoPoint setgeopoint (double dl, double dlong) {
        int intl = (int) (dl*1000000);
        int intlong = (int) (dlong*1000000);

        GeoPoint point= new GeoPoint ( intl, intlong);
        return point;
    }




    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            if (loc != null) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude()
                                + " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gps[0]= lat2;
                gps[1]=longitude2;
                gps[0] = loc.getLatitude();
                gps[1] = loc.getLongitude();
                z=loc.getSpeed();

            }
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps     Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Status changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }





}'
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.SmartPark"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses- permission> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS"></uses-permission>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:name=".MapviewActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.SmartPark/com.SmartPark.MapviewActivity}:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.SmartPark.MapviewActivity in loader     dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.SmartPark-2.apk]
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.SmartPark.MapviewActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.SmartPark-2.apk]
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)
10-06 09:19:07.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13602):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Pay no mind to location of "uses library". I posted the wrong manifest. I moved the maps library to be a child of the application tag with same error. Fixed Manifest shown above. Still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `MapViewActivity` and  not `MapviewActivity` in your manifest?

Comment: As inspired by Las Vegas! I had combined two different programs into the one program, but when I copied and pasted the manifest from my MapView activity, I didn't change the name of the activity to SmartPark. DER!!! Thank you Las Vegas for inspiring me. The appropriate activity name should be SmartParkActivity...NOT MapView.

Answer (score 2):

add uses library in application tag...(You add in activity tag...)

So your androidmanifiest is below ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.SmartPark"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"></uses-permission> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS">    </uses-permission>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
    <activity android:name=".SmartParkActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I tried that, but it still doesn't work. Same error.  The manifest posted was where I had tried moving the maps file, but it still didn't work. fixed manifest shown above.